# How can I define a systemd target to start on boot or after another target

Tags: linux, systemd

I would like to know how I can define in a unit file for a systemd target i.e. `/etc/systemd/system/sample.target`

that it should be run at the multi-user.target level.

In a unit file for a service I might do something like this

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In a target this would clearly not work so I am wondering how I could define this for a target.

I would like to create a target that runs as if it is WantedBy=multi-user.target

Comment: You want [Requires=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html).

Comment: what does the `.-` mean in this context. I know that `-` means ignore the error, so just curious what the dot does. Also My current work around is to put my target in the `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/` directory.

Comment: That's a full stop at the end of my comment... Your current approach is correct, by the way.

Comment: You can also specify After=

Comment: O man I read that comment all wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> [Install]
> WantedBy=multi-user.target
> ```
>
> In a target this would clearly not work

It works just fine for targets such as `remote-fs.target`; and the `systemd.target` manual page is clear that the `[Install]` section is valid in target units.  So use it.

Comment: For whatever reason this is not working on Ubuntu:16.04, I tried it.

Comment: I tried this once more and I can confirm for sure that this does not work

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
[Unit]
Description=ABRT Automated Bug Reporting Tool
After=syslog.target
[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=com.redhat.abrt
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/abrtd -d -s
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```